# First hitting time

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, stopping-times

Let $ B=(B_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a Brownian Motion and $a \in \mathbb R$, and 
$\tau_a:=\inf \{ t\geq 0 :B_t =a \} $ is a finite stopping time.

How can we prove that :

$$ \mathbb E(\tau_a)=\infty \;\;\text{ and } \;\;\limsup_{t \to \infty}B_t=+\infty\; a.s  $$ $ \;\;\liminf_{t \to \infty}B_t=-\infty\;$ a.s

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/531225/36150) you find two proofs that $\mathbb{E}(\tau_a)=\infty$. For the limiting behaviour of Brownian motion, note that $(-B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a Brownian motion, and therefore it suffices to show that $$\limsup_{t \to \infty} B_t = \infty \quad \text{a.s.}\tag{1}$$ This is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1284858/36150) using martingale methods. Alternatively, you can also use the reflection principle. Since Brownian motion has continuous sample paths (hence bounded on compact time intervals), it follows that $(1)$ is equivalent to saying that $\mathbb{P}(\tau_a<\infty)=1$ for all $a>0$. By the reflection principle,

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_a \leq t) = \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{s \leq t} B_s \geq a \right) = \mathbb{P}(|B_t| \geq a) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{t} |B_1| \geq a),$$

and so

$$\mathbb{P}(\tau_a < \infty) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(\tau_a \leq t) = \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|B_1| \geq a/\sqrt{t})=1$$ for all $a>0$.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful, i have two question: first question why we have $ \mathbb{P}(|B_t| \geq a) = \mathbb{P}(\sqrt{t} |B_1| \geq a) $  ? and second question is why we have $  \lim_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(|B_1| \geq a/\sqrt{t})=0 $ ?

Comment: @Joel Since $B_t$ is Gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $t$, it equals in distribution $\sqrt{t} B_1$ (... because $\sqrt{t} B_1$ is also Gaussian, with mean zero and variance t). Re your 2nd question: It was actually a typo; the limit equals $1$ (not zero).